# Array in While Loop PHP

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop

I have a while loop that loops through line of text

```
while ($line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_processing, 4096)) {
```

In this while loop I assign variables to different parts of the array

```
   IF($i > 0)
   {
    echo "</br>";
    $account_type_id = $line_of_text[0];
    echo "Account Type ID: " . $account_type_id. "<br>";

    $account_number = $line_of_text[1];
    echo "account_number = " . $account_number . "<br>";
```

This while  loop loops through many lines. I am trying to find a way to say that

IF $account_type_id == 99 then add $account_number to an array. Then outside of the while loop print out the whole array of $account_numbers where $account_type_id == 99.

I have tried using print_r but it will only display the last array...

Comment: `if($account_type_id == 99){ $account_numbers[] = $account_numbers; }`?

Answer (score 1):

To add the element to an array, you can use [array_push](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_push.asp).

First you need to create the array (**before** the while loop):

```
$my_array = array();
```

Then, in the `while` loop, do this:

```
if ($account_type_id == 99) {
    array_push($my_array, $account_number);
}
```

Then to display the array, either use `print_r`or `var_dump`. To make the array easier to read, you can also do this:

```
echo "<pre>".print_r($my_array, 1)."</pre>";
```

Comment: $my_array = new array(); is not PHP syntax.

Comment: Simple mistake to change. Don't see the need to downvote, but hey ho!

Comment: you can refer to my first comment.

Comment: But the rest was correct. As I said, a simple mistake was made and it was now been rectified. My last comment was just to check I had not made any other mistakes ;)

Answer (score 0):

Rocket H had the answer in the comment he posted

inside of your loop

```
if($account_type_id == 99){
    $account_numbers[] = $account_number;
   }
```

After loop

```
print_r($account_numbers);
```